# changing email associated with account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I will be losing the email which is associated with this account over the summer, and I would like to switch it over to my new email. I added a new account on my new email (now a poor decision in hindsight) and I would like to find a way to switch the email on this account to my new email. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Click your username > Edit Profile & Settings > enter a different email address?

Comment: Helpful link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers

Answer (score 4):

You can change your possible logins by opening your profile, going to <kbd>Settings</kbd>><kbd>My Logins</kbd> and managing the accounts listed there:

[image: Walkthrough]

Comment: That 13,074 really is too big :p